# Rails hosting for small photo app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, hosting, dreamhost

I'm making a small photo-gallery app.  The photos will be hosted locally.  Right now I use dreamhost but their rails implementation looks horrible.  So I'm looking for other options.  I know Heroku gives you one 'web dyno' for free, but they don't say anything about how much space you get.  As I said, I want my photos stored locally with the app, I don't want to deal with s3 or other cloud storage.

Answer (score 4):

there is no local storage with heroku - only temporary space.  you'll need to use S3 or some off-site storage with heroku.

(and I agree, rails on DH is awful, even if you enable passenger)

Comment: one kind of ugly option is to create a very simple save/load script on DH and use DH for storage and Herkou for your app.  it would probably be best to do that using PHP or some other lighter-weight web framework.

Comment: I don't have a heroku account right now, so there's really not a point in my signing up unless it's easy to use for my purposes.  If I ever decide I want to use S3, then it's a good option.

Answer (score 2):

Use Openshift to deploy your app
checkout this [deploying rails app in openshift](http://ror-tech.blogspot.in/2013/04/deploying-rails-application-on-to.html)

openshift provides one permanent data directory to store data and its free

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in VPS, Digital Ocean - https://www.digitalocean.com/, provides excellent hosting starting from $5. And you can store your photos on the local disc.

There are very good tutorials on their site to get you started with.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Shelly Cloud: https://shellycloud.com/ You get persistent storage (so you don't lose data in case of disk failure) and the deployment is optimized for Rails applications.

Comment: Looks good but it's pricey and the servers are hosted in Europe....  Probably too much for what I want.

Answer (score 0):

With Heroku you can host images that you store in the repository of your project. Just try this:

```
rails new mytest
```

create a simple page and link to a test image in your `/app/assets/images`

```
heroku create mytest123  # <-- mytest1234 must be your unique app name
```

and now push the repo to Heroku:

```
git push origin master  # origin points automatically to Heroku after you created this
```

This is the easiest way to host small projects for free. Sometimes the Dyno takes some time to startup, and you need to point the domain to the right proxy, but these issues can be dealt with later.

S3 comes into play when you deal with uploaded content / images. For this use case, you need S3 which is out of the scope of your question too.

Comment: I was gonna have uploaded content...  No reason to store my photos on git.   The size of the app itself is small but the photo content will eventually grow.